# Cassandra "Connection has been closed" using Java Spark Driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, cql

Sometimes when I'm trying to connect to a Cassandra node using Spark in Java, the following exception is thrown:

```
Connection has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:38)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:313)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:269)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:143)
    at database.Spark.prepareMaps(Spark.java:97)
    at database.Spark.main(Spark.java:755)
```

re-run the code again, with no changes, everything works well.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
cassandraConnector = CassandraConnector.apply(javaSparkContext.getConf());
        try {
            session = cassandraConnector.openSession();
            LOGGER.info("Connected successfully to Cassandra");
        } catch (

        Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Couldn't connect to Cassandra or error in query");
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here ... Are you  saying just opening a session is causing the connection to fail?

Comment: No. The connection is opened successfully. But when executing a query SOMETIMES it gets closed for no reason !

Comment: Hey RussS, do you have any idea about what got wrong here?

Comment: without any more code it's pretty hard to tell. Are you opening a session every single time you want to run a query?